# I have a square, and place three dots along the 4 edges at random. What is the probability that the dots lie on distinct edges?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

The correct answer is listed as (3/4) * (1/2) = 3/8. The reasoning is because it doesn't matter where you put the first dot, but after you put the first dot, it is 3/4 chance of a different edge, and then 1/2 chance of another different edge.

However, if I think about it from a purely combinatorics way, there are "4" ways that three dots can be arranged on the square in which all dots are on distinct edges. There are then 12 ways that two dots can be on one edge and the third dot is on another edge (4 edges to put two dots, multiplied by 3 possible edges to put the third dot). Finally, there are 4 ways to put all three dots onto a single edge. This gives us (4/20) probability where the three dots are on distinct edges. This should work since each dot is independent of the previous dot and we can assume a uniform probability distribution.

Why are these two values different?

Comment: You are assuming that all "configurations" are equally likely.  This is not the case, because when placing the three dots, there are more ways to arrive at some configurations than others.  In particular, there are 6 ways to arrive at each 3-edge configuration; 3 ways to arrive at each 2-edge configuration; and only one way to arrive at each single-edge configuration.  Taking this into account, the probability of reaching a 3-edge configuration is $(4\cdot 6) / (4\cdot 6 + 12 \cdot 3 + 4\cdot 1)=24/64=3/8$.

Comment: "*I place three dots on the edges* **at random**"  The phrase "at random" is not specific enough.  Depending on how the random processes are formalized you can get different probabilities.  See [Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).  The most natural choice of how to randomly assign the dots to the edges is to take your first dot and place it on one of the four edges uniformly at random... then take your second dot and place it on one of the four edges uniformly at random and chosen independently of the first, then do the same for the third.