# Distribute three balls in four boxes.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

You are distributing 3 balls among 4 boxes, each one randomly and independent of the others - what is the probability that all 3 balls go to different boxes? - For this problem, what would the answer be? I am thinking:

4C3 / ((3+4-1)C3) = 1/5, where the numerator is the number of configurations with each ball in a different box, and the denominator is all possible configurations of 3 balls in 4 boxes.

**Is this question different from:** [I have a square, and place three dots along the 4 edges at random. What is the probability that the dots lie on distinct edges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244692/i-have-a-square-and-place-three-dots-along-the-4-edges-at-random-what-is-the-p/4724449#4724449) - Because the answer to this question from what I have gathered is 1 * 3/4 * 2/4 = 3/8.

Why are the two questions different? Thanks!

Comment: The problems appear to be equivalent with the proviso that, in the case of the square, it's not clear to me what happens if you place a dot at a corner.  Perhaps the rules exclude that (and the stated answer appears to assume that this is excluded).

Comment: I don't understand your first answer here.  The first one goes in whatever box.  The next is in a new one with probability $\frac 34$ and the third differs from the first two with probability $\frac 24$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is wrong: it **is** similar to the square question and has the same answer of $\frac38$ and can be solved exactly as it has been for the second problem.

However, there is more than one way to solve the first question, eg Place balls in $4*3*2$ ways against a total possible of $4^3$ ways, giving $Pr= \dfrac{24}{64}=\dfrac38$

**Note**

By the way, your attempt for the first question is quite confused. "You are distributing $3$ balls among $4$ boxes, **each one randomly and independent of the others**"
(i) You need to be clear whether a problem is a permutation type or combination type or (sometimes) solvable using either of the two in a consistent way.
(ii) Stars and bars does **not** distribute randomly and independently of others

Comment: Hi @trueblueanil, thanks for responding! Could you please expand on the bottom paragraph, as I think that is where I'm confused. I think my solution fails because I made the following mistake:

The probability of ending up with 2 balls in one box and 1 ball in another is different from ending up with all 3 balls in the same box which is different from each ball ending up in its own box, correct? Initially, I thought these three events are all equally likely because the balls are placed randomly, but I understand that this is not the case as some cases have more combinations.

Comment: Yes, stars and bars just counts all possible ways, but the different ways are not equiprobable. Just by commonsense, we can see that all $3$ balls in one box is less likely than a more even distribution. It helps to slot a problem into a well known *type*, where possible. Here, you can think of throwing a $4$ faced die $3$ times as the prototype.